# Current Noise Source. New Symbol needed

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, circuitikz

I write a code for the Voltage and Current Noise Sources, using the "circuit declare symbol". The option works well for the Noise Voltage. I can change the color of the font, circumference and Pattern, because all are based in a primitive figure "circle ee". But I have a problem with the Current Noise Source, I created a "Shortcut" but the solution is not elegant. Because, when I change the dimensions of my circuit, everything fails. I think I need a new symbol, but i don't know how to construct it. The reference for the circuit is INop source.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
%\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture} [
circuit ee IEC,
x=1.2cm,y=0.9cm,
every info/.style={font=\tiny},
font=\scriptsize,
small circuit symbols,
circuit declare symbol=sR, 
       set sR graphic={fill=white,draw,shape=circle,minimum size=5mm
}
    ]
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------Circuit
% Contact Nodes
\foreach \contact/\x in {1/2,2/4}
{
 \node [contact] (L1P\contact) at (\x,0) {};    %L1Px Line 1 Contact Point \x
 \node [contact] (L2P\contact) at (\x,3) {};    %L1Px Line 1 Contact Point \x
}

\draw (5.5,1.5) node [op amp, thick,scale=1] (opamp) {};
\draw (L1P1) node[rground, scale=1] {};

\draw (0,3) to [sV=$Us_i$] (0,0);

\draw (0,0) -- (2,0);

\draw (0,3) to [
    black, sR={black,near start,info={$U_{NRi}$},
            pattern=north west lines,pattern color = black!80,scale=1}, 
    resistor={near end,info=$R_i$,scale=0.9}
    ] (L2P1);

\draw (L2P1) to [
    resistor={near start,info=$R_1$,scale=0.9}, 
    black, sR={black,near end, 
            info=left:{$U_{NR_1}$},pattern=north west lines,
            pattern color = black!80,scale=1}
    ] (L1P1);

\draw (L1P1) to [
    resistor={near start,info=$R_2$,scale=0.9},
    black, sR={near end,info={$U_{NR_2}$},
            pattern=north west lines,pattern color = black!80,scale=1}
    ] (L1P2);
% ----------------------------------------One possibility for the Noise Source.
    % Here my version of the Symbol, but I found very ineffective. Very manual.
\path (L1P2) to [black,sR={black,
           pattern=north west lines,pattern color = blue!80}] (4,2.55);
\path (4,0.45) to [black, sR={black,
           info=left:{\tiny$I_{Nop}$},pattern=north west lines,
           pattern color = blue!80}] (L2P2);

\draw (L1P2) -- (4,1.04); %Disadvantage
\draw (L2P2) -- (4,1.96); %Disadvantage
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\draw (L2P2) to [
black,sR={black,info={$U_{Nop}$},pattern=north west lines,pattern color = black}
] (L2P1);

\draw (L2P2) -- (4.5,3) -- (opamp.-);
\draw (L1P2) -- (4.5,0) -- (opamp.+) (opamp.out) node [ right ] {$Us_{o}$}; 
    %-------------------------------------------------Ende der Schaltung    
    \end{tikzpicture}%}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. here is important to know which tikz-packages you use ...

Comment: Thank you, i made the modification. When I will have 10 points, I will add an Image, because I think it clarify a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to my problem using geometric concepts, but the code is a little large. I will like to generate something like a function, any help. Here is the Code. You Only need two points and the code draw the Noise Current Source. The First Coordinate always is the point up other left.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{german, ngerman}  
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                              
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
germandbls={ß},}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkzexample}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}  %New Library

\setlength\parindent{0pt}


\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture} [
circuit ee IEC,
x=1cm,y=2cm,
every info/.style={font=\tiny},
font=\scriptsize,
small circuit symbols,
circuit declare symbol=sR, 
     set sR graphic={fill=white,draw,shape=circle,minimum size=5mm}
   ]
   %---------------------------------------------------------------Contact Points
% Contact Nodes
\foreach \contact/\x in {1/1}
{
\node [contact] (L1P\contact) at (\x,0) {};     %L1Px Line 1 Contact Point \x
\node [contact] (L2P\contact) at (\x,3) {};     %L1Px Line 1 Contact Point \x
}
\draw (L1P1) node[rground, scale=1] {};

%%%%%%%% Probando sin Funcion  Codigo Final  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%------------------------------------------- Drawing the Stromrauschquelle
%--------------------------------------------------Coordinate Calculations
\coordinate (A) at (L2P1);
\coordinate (B) at (L1P1);
\coordinate (C) at ($(A)!0.5!B)$);
\node [name path = Circle,opacity=0][sR,scale=2] (P) at (C) {};
    %-------------------------------------------------Intersection Calculations
\path [name path=Line] (A)--(B);
 \path [name intersections={of=Line and Circle}];
\coordinate (D) at (intersection-1);
\coordinate (E) at (intersection-2);
% Calculating the new centers of the circles.
\coordinate (F) at ($(D) !0.30!(C)$);   
\coordinate (G) at ($(C) !0.70!(E)$);      
% Calculating Radio of the circles based on the original circle.
\draw let \p1 = ($(D)-(C)$),
          \n0={veclen(\x1,\y1)}
          in 
          node[draw,name path = Circle1,circle,minimum size = 2*\n0,
          pattern=north west lines,pattern color = blue!80] (P1) at (F) {}
          node[draw,name path = Circle2,circle,minimum size = 2*\n0,
          pattern=north west lines,pattern color = blue!80] (P2) at (G) {};

% Two Path Lines pro calculate the intersection H and I for the lines.
    % This is needed because our figure can rotate.
\draw [name path = Line1, draw=none] (A) -- (D);      
\draw [name path = Line2, draw=none] (B) -- (E);     
 \path [name intersections={of=Line1 and Circle1}];
 \coordinate (H) at (intersection-1);  
\path [name intersections={of=Line2 and Circle2}];
\coordinate (I) at (intersection-1);
% Now  we can choose which line would we want for the lines between A-H and B-I
\draw (A) -- (H);
\draw (B) -- (I);   


    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Stromquelle Stufe 1}
    \label{Fig:IN01}
    \end{figure}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \end{document}
```